# How can I know the number of roots of a pseudo-polynomial?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials, roots

I am interested in knowing the number of roots of a function which can be transformed in into a polynomial with a simple substitution. 
For eg: $Bx + C\sqrt{x} + D = 0$, which can be transformed into a polynomial with substituting $y = \sqrt{x}$.

I can't just say that #roots is the degree of polynomial after substitution because it does not work.

eg: $x^2 - 5x -5(x)^{1/2} +4=0$ has 2 real roots.

$x^2 -20x +50 \sqrt{x} -6 = 0$ has 2 complex and 1 real roots.

Any easy way to do this other than solving the polynomial itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends very much on what kind of substitution you do. Let's say that it is $y=f(x)$.

For each root $y_0$ of the polynomial on $y$, there will be as many roots of the pseudo-polynomial as elements in the set $f^{-1}(\{y_0\})$. So, for example, if $f$ is a bijection, pseudo-polynomial on $x$ and polynomial on $y$ have the same number of roots.

Comment: I did not get "Let's say that it is  y = f(x)". What is f(x) ? Is f(x) the pseudo polynomial function ?

Comment: It is the substitution. In your example, $y=\sqrt x$.

Comment: So I need to do a substitution that is bijective. Thanks, anyway If I want to prove this how can I do that ?